# AWS Cloudformation integration with github

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Well, I'm starting to use AWS CloudFormation to provision my infra as a code. So I have some doubts about it:

1. My cloudformation code is inside github, I would like to trigger a cloudformation stack update automatically when I new commit is made in the master branch. Is this possible?
2. Cloudformation can provision my EC2 instances, but I need to configure these instances after this, for example: Install nginx, change port in nginx, move files, and so on. How can I automate it using cloudformation ?

Comment: Can check out https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cfn-lint-action for CloudFormation-specific PR comments on Github as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can set up a two-step CodePipeline, which [uses GitHub as the source/trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-GitHub.html). In the second step configure a CloudFormation action that updates your stack.
2. You have a few options here:

- Create your own AMI with all additional packages installed.
- Use [user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) to install packages at instance startup time.
- Dockerize your app, and launch it in ECS/EC2 instead of raw EC2.